# Fullcalendar Event drop and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, fullcalendar

I'm currently working with the great Jquery plugin - Fullcalendar but I'm encountering a problem. I use the eventDrop listener and I want to send the event information using Ajax to my server side.

My code is the following :

```
eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: ("/PSAdmin/RFCalendar/DragEvent"),
                    data: ({
                        type: event.className,
                        delta: dayDelta,
                        newDate: event.start,
                        newTitle: event.title
                    }),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#calendar').empty();
                        loadCalendar();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                });
}
```

My problem is that as soon as I try to send any variable contained into the event object, it doesn't work. For example sending only dayDelta to the server side works, but none of the event.something does.

If anyone stumbled on this problem before or if you have any idea what could cause the problem, please let me know.

Comment: Your code should work perfectly. `Please check in console that your event.something have their values.` You can cache event.something to variables and then use those variable to pass as data object.

Comment: I alerted each value and they are all good but when they reach my server they are null.

Comment: Did you inspect the network requests using your browser's devtools or using Fiddler or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unfortunately, I couldn't figure out why the ajax query wasn't working properly and I had to do what i didn't want to do originally.

```
if (event.className == "holiday") {
                    var className = "holiday";
                }

                //build date
                var date = event.start.getMonth()+1 + "/" + event.start.getDate() + "/" + event.start.getFullYear();
                alert(date);

                $.ajax({
                    url: ("/PSAdmin/RFCalendar/DragEvent/"),
                    data: ({
                        className: className,
                        delta: dayDelta,
                        newDate: date,
                        newTitle: event.title
                    }),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#calendar').empty();
                        loadCalendar();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                });
```

It's ugly and time consuming but at least it works. I have other priorities to work on but if you have any clue about this problem, please let me know.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I hade a similiar problem with nothing getting sent to the server. Tried everything, caching aswell as using jquery to extend and copy the object.

What worked for me was looking at the headers, for the request. They always seemed to have the data.

I ended up with this code serverside. Not what I want but it could probably help somebody trying to tackle the same problem!

**C#**

```
[HttpGet]
    public void UpdateOrderData(object orderObj)
    {
        var obj = new
        {
            start = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["orderObj[start]"]),
            end = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["orderObj[end]"]),
            date = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["orderObj[date]"]),
            resourceId = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["orderObj[resourceId]"]),
            orderId = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["orderObj[orderId]"]),
        };

        calendarUnitOfWork.CustomDataRepository.UpdateOrderData(obj);
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
 myModel.eventDrop = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) 
 {
     calUOW.orderrepository.updateOrderData({
            start: event.start.format(),
            end: event.end.format(),
            date: event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            resourceId: event.resourceId,
            orderId: event.orderId
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem today. So here is the function that i wrote for eventDrop. You can add the JS code to your page in  tags or whereever you use fullcalendar init function. Hope it helps.

**Javascript:**

```
       eventDrop: function(event) {
          console.log(event.event);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
                    },
                    url: "YOUR POST URL HERE",
                    data: {
                        id: event.event._def.publicId, // Event id for DB
                        start:event.event.startStr,  // Event start timestamp
                        end:event.event.endStr, // Event end timestamp
                        allDay:event.event.allDay // Event allDay Boolean
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                       console.log('success')
                    }
                });
            },
```

I use Laravel 9 for my small application. So here is a PHP function that i use for editing fullcalendar events.

**PHP Function:**

```
    public function drop_json_appointments(Request $request)
    {
    $app = Appointment::where('id', $request->input('id'))->first();
    $start = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $end = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if($request->input('allDay') == 'false') $allDay = 0; else $allDay =1;
    Appointment::where('id', $request->input('id'))->update([
        'start'=>$start,
        'end'=>$end,
        'allDay'=>$allDay,
    ]);
    return response()->json('success');
    }
```

Also you should add the "resize event" of fullcalendar. Here is the resize function. PHP function is the same.

**Resize Event Javascript:**

```
 eventResize: function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: "SAME AJAX URL",
                    data: {
                        id: event.event._def.publicId,
                        start:event.event.startStr,
                        end:event.event.endStr,
                        allDay:event.event.allDay
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log('success')
                    }
                });


            },
```